# I want to install and connect to openVPN on windows machine through windows CLI commands

Tags: azure-devops, command-line, openvpn, openvpn-connect

I want to install and connect to openVPN on windows machine through windows CLI commands, please help

In ubuntu machine we are able to install and connect it but through windows command prompt we are unable to do it, please help

These commands I need to execute in azure devops pipeline which runs on microsoft hosted windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Run OpenVPN from a command prompt Window with a command such as: openvpn myconfig.ovpn. ...